# Why do I need to declare Node as a struct in the Node struct and not just as a Node object?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, queue, declaration

I am creating a linked list implementation of the stack. In the `Node` struct, I have the data members `data` and `next`. My question is, why does the data member `next` need to be declared like `struct Node * next` and not just like `Node *next`?

```
template <class T>
class Stack{
    private:
        struct Node{
            T data;
            struct Node *next; //This is what the question is in reference to
        };

        Node *front;
        Node *end;

    public:
};
```

Comment: If this were C, you would need the `struct`, but it's not. I'm guessing that you didn't actually try without it.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to write `Node *next;` instead of `struct Node *next;` in this context, and it does not change the meaning. The inclusion of the keyword `struct` is superfluous, and if I had to guess, the author included it because they are accustomed to writing in C, where (in contrast to C++) it may not be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ these two structure definitions

```
struct Node{
    T data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

and

```
struct Node{
    T data;
    Node *next;
};
```

are equivalent. Within the structure definition the name `Node` is the injected class name.

From the C++ 20 Standard (6.4.2 Point of declaration)

> 8 The point of declaration for an injected-class-name (11.1) is
> immediately following the opening brace of the class definition.

Opposite to C++ in C this structure definition

```
struct Node{
    T data;
    Node *next;
};
```

is invalid because the name `Node` used as a tag name in this record `struct Node` and the name `Node` used in this member declaration `Node *next;` belong to different name spaces. The name `Node` in this declaration of data member

```
Node *next;
```

is not yet declared.

You could make the structure definition in C valid by using a typedef like

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node{
    T data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Pay attention to that if you want to define a stack then the data member

```
Node *end;
```

is redundant.